# PDF Commenting Feature for delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-2009

I'm looking for an application that will allow me to add mark-ups to pdfs just like adobe acrobat does via the comments option (e.g. stickynotes), including the options of hiding all comments, showing, printing and saving them to the pdf.  My application is written using delphi 2009 and this is an additional feature I require.
There doesn't appear to be any vcl providers out there doing this at the moment (?). I've contacted quickpdf, vispdf, etc, etc
I'm particularly interested in hearing from anyone who has done this already / can do this,
thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 2):

[Gnostice](http://www.gnostice.com/) are well known for their PDF components for Delphi, specifically [PDFtoolkit](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp).

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, [Amyuni PDF Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) allows to select (and create) specific components within a PDF file (such as text, images or annotations) and change their attributes. It can be used in Delphi as an ActiveX control.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies at the time of writing this answer.